# PDF of sum of (1/(1+uniform distribution)) and a normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution, density-function

I have a continuous uniform random variable $P\sim U(0,1)$ and a normal random variable $X \sim N(0,\sigma)$. If $Z$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
Z = \frac{1}{1+P}+X
\end{equation}
where $X$ and $P$ are independent variables, how can I calculate the PDF of Z?

Any help anyone can give to guide me towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried calculating the convolution of the PDFs with Mathematica as discussed here (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245868/pdf-of-sum-of-1-1uniform-distribution-and-a-normal-distribution). Mathematica and (thanks to JimB!) Rubi both failed to find an explicit solution for the PDF of $Z$.

Comment: You cannot, unless you know the joint distribution of $X$ and $P$.

Comment: How is this different from the PDF of $Z=P+X$, such as discussed here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204711/pdf-sum-of-a-normal-distribution-and-a-uniform-distribution ?

Comment: Edited the question to make it clear that $P$ and $X$ are independent variables.

Comment: Density of a sum two independent random variables is the convolution of the densities of those variables. You should be able to this calculation on your own.

Comment: Is that the convolution of the PDFs of $1/(1+P)$ and $X$?

Comment: Yes, that is what it is.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245868/pdf-of-sum-of-1-1uniform-distribution-and-a-normal-distribution.